# how to append hidden field value to input text field before submitting?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<form id="contactForm">
    <input type="text" value="100" id="number" name="number" />
    <input type="hidden" value="00" id="decimal" name="decimal" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit-form" />
</form>
<script>
     var form = document.getElementById('contactForm');
        form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
          var input = document.createElement('number');
          input.type = 'text';
          input.name = 'decimal';
          input.value = '00';
          this.appendChild(input);
        }, true);
</script>
```

// I want it to append the decimal '00' to the input number before submitting the form.

// I want the result as = 10000

Comment: Your script is invalid. var form = document.getElementById('#contact-form'); should be without the hash. Or should rather use querySelector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>


<form id="contact-form">
    <input type="text" value="100" id="number" name="number" />
    <input type="hidden" value="00" id="decimal" name="decimal" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit-form" id="clickme" />
</form>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
   $(document).ready(function(){

        //in here ,first check the existing value with an alert when document is ready
     var hiddenValue = $("#decimal").val();
     alert("before value :" + hiddenValue);


        //in this part you can assign the new value

     $("#clickme").click(function(){
      var newhiddenVal = "new decimal";
      $("#decimal").val(newhiddenVal);
      var displaynewHiddenvalue = $("#decimal").val();
      alert(displaynewHiddenvalue);
     });
   });


</script>

</html>
```

note : to understand, first it shows the existing value, then in the button click , assign your new value , then display.(display with alsert, because then you can understand easily)

to assign the values in button click

```
var newhiddenVal = "new decimal";
$("#decimal").val(newhiddenVal);
```

do above in button click. hope this will help.

to get `10000` as the new value, in your button click

```
 $("#clickme").click(function(){
            var newhiddenVal = $("#number").val() +hiddenValue;
            $("#decimal").val(newhiddenVal);
            var displaynewHiddenvalue = $("#decimal").val();
            alert(displaynewHiddenvalue);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you but m still facing the problem.. i have tried but what is the main thing is that... The the final value i.e (1000) need to bind in the "number" value.

Comment: you mean you need it as an integer

Comment: yes.. actually the new value "1000" need to be the value for "number" in the action_page.php [number].

Comment: this gives a string, then you have to convert it into integer like this
`var integerValue = parseInt("your string",10);` this will give you the integer value of above string.

Answer (score 0):

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
          var decimal_val= document.getElementByName('decimal').value;
          var number= document.getElementByName('number').value;
          number = decimal_val+number;
        }, true);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an [explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/305455) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!